# Bootstrap modal not working, doesn't popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the template modal given on Bootstrap's web site but for some reason it is not working. The button shows with the hand icon so I know that my CDN is correct. Where am I wrong?

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span> My information</a>
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"> Enter your information</h4>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <h4> Text about you</h4>    
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is within your button. You need to set `data-toggle` to `modal` and `data-target` to the ID of the modal, ie. `#myModal`.

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span> My information
  </a>
  <div class="modal fade" role="dialog" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"> Enter your information</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4> Text about you</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See working sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iFGLeRyQn8Gqb0tEf2A9?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

make sure the order of your `js` files are like this and are present

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

seems like you haven't included a `jquery` file. 
here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u9Lq1kc2/)